# Can you just clear specific entity types from JPA Entity Manager cache

Tags: jpa, caching, entity

In the raw JPA specification (so not a specific implementation like Hibernate or EclipseLink), is there an option to call `em.clear()` for a specific type of entity but not for others?

The reason I'm asking is, I have a process which creates and stores tens of thousands of entities; but each is not needed again by the entity manager after it's been persisted. However, each entity has a child entity which is one of about 30 records in the database. So I want to be able to call something like `em.clear(MainEntity.class)`, meaning I don't clear the cache of the child entity which is reused, but also don't build up a history of tens of thousands of unneeded records.

Here's a simplified example of what I am currently doing:

```java
List<Child> children = (List<Child>)em.createQuery("Select c from " + Child.entityName + " c").getResultList();

for (int i=0;i<700000;i++)
{
    Parent p = createParent(i, getRandomChild(children));
    em.persist(p);
    
    if (i%1000 == 0)
    {
         em.flush(); // push to db
         em.clear(); // remove old items from cache - but unfortunately removes children too
        // as I've cleared the cache, I need to repopulate this to reattach the children again
        children = (List<Child>)em.createQuery("Select c from " + Child.entityName + " c").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
void detach(java.lang.Object entity)
```

like this

```
em.detach(p);
```

to remove only parent from the persistence context.

Comment: This removed a specific instance of `Parent`, rather than all instances of class `Parent`, though, right?

Comment: That's right. You could loop or alternatively create a new helping class with CascadeType.DETACH on the oneToMany relationship from the new helping class to the parent entity. And then detach the helping class.

Comment: The helper class is an interesting approach, thanks. Can you put some of that into your answer?